# Google VR how to perform selection with daydream controller

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0, daydream

Following is my case

- I have a rectangle with `left=0,right=1824,top=0,bottom=989` with aspect ratio 1.84f, with uniform  `z axis = -3f`
- In that rectangle, I have small rectangles with width and height of 344 and 182. I arrange those small rectangles in the 3 rows and 3 columns similar to a grid gallery.
- I did some modification in the orthographic projection without changing the z axis such that the new rectangle will be in range `-1,84 to 1.84 in x axis` and `1 to -1 in y axis` and all the small rectangles lie in those range
- Then to render those rectangles on VR, I simply applied

  `view = perspective ( z near 0.1f, far 100 f) * eye.getEyeVew
  model = Orthographic transformation to come in range ( -1.84f to 1.84 f : X , 1 to 1f :Y )
  modelview = view * model`
- To emulate the controller, I used a simple circle with `( centerX=0, centerY=0, radius =0.04f, zaxis = -3f)`
- Applied following transformation to the circle with controller rotation matrix (https://developers.google.com/vr/reference/android/com/google/vr/sdk/controller/Orientation.html#toRotationMatrix(float[]))

  `view = perspective ( z near 0.1f, far 100 f) * eye.getEyeVew
  controllerMatrix = controller.toRotationMatrix
  modelView = view * controllerMatrix`

My assumption was following,

- Since, I was drawing the 3D planes with uniform Z values, I can consider them as a 2D plane for selection.
- I assumed that the circle 2D coordinate ( left,top,right,bottom) can be used to check with the plane 2D coordinate ( left,top,right,bottom) and see whether the circle falls in the the plane or not.
- But due to the perspective & eye.getEyeView transformation, the z axis of both the circle and plane changes.

So, my question is for this purpose should I go for RayCasting or there is a simple solution for selecting the small rectangles with VR controller.
I am using GVR controller `( Google VR version 1.80.0 )` and using Android for app development.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Google VR SDK comes with some useful example projects which demonstrate how to achieve this. If you inspect the [Treasure Hunt project](https://github.com/googlevr/gvr-android-sdk/tree/master/samples/sdk-treasurehunt), the `TreasureHuntActivity` class has a method `isLookingAtObject()`:

```
private boolean isLookingAtObject() {
    // Convert object space to camera space. Use the headView from onNewFrame.
    Matrix.multiplyMM(modelView, 0, headView, 0, modelCube, 0);
    Matrix.multiplyMV(tempPosition, 0, modelView, 0, POS_MATRIX_MULTIPLY_VEC, 0);

    float pitch = (float) Math.atan2(tempPosition[1], -tempPosition[2]);
    float yaw = (float) Math.atan2(tempPosition[0], -tempPosition[2]);

    return Math.abs(pitch) < PITCH_LIMIT && Math.abs(yaw) < YAW_LIMIT;
}
```

This will calculate the angle between the vector in the direction of the cameras line of sight and `modelCube` matrix. The `modelCube` matrix is a 4x4 matrix defining the scale, rotation and translation for the centre point of an object in the 3D scene. In your case this will be the centre point of the rectangle in 3D space.

You must also calculate the angles where the vector that defines the pointing direction of the camera intersects the rectangle. This is depicted in the following diagram:

[image]

Here the origin is your camera position, the point C is the centroid of the rectangle rendered in 3D space and the vector **OC** is the direction vector your camera is pointing in when it is focused directly on the centre of the rectangle. Ꝋ is the angle from the X-axis to the point C in the X-Z plane. Points P1-4 are are vertices of your rectangle in 3D space.

The pitch ɸ is defined in the following diagram:

[image]

Here ɸ is the angle from the centre point **C** to the new axis **e**.

The `PITCH_LIMIT` is the angle in the Y-**e** plane between two vectors. the vector from the camera position to the bottom edge of the bounding box of the object and the vector from the camera position to the upper edge of the bounding box of the object. In this case it can be calculated as either the angle between **OP3** and **OP4** or the angle between **OP2** and **OP1**. This is depicted in the following 2D cross section:

[image]

Assume that the camera is looking directly at the rectangle, this limit defines how much the camera must be tilted up before the centre of the camera is no longer pointing directly at the rectangle.

The `YAW_LIMIT` is the angle in the X-Z plane between two vectors, the vector from the camera position to the left-most edge of the bounding box of the object, and the vector from the camera position to the right-most edge of the bounding box of the object. In this case it can be calculated as either the angle between **OP1** and **OP4** or the angle between **OP2** and **OP3**. This is depicted in the following 2D cross section:

[image]

Likewise, this limit defines how much the camera can be rotated left or right before the centre of the camera is no longer pointing directly at the rectangle.

Note that the `YAW_LIMIT` and `PITCH_LIMIT` values get smaller if you are further away from the object and larger if you are close. You must calculate these limits for the object that you want to check is being looked at based on the current camera position and edge vertices of the object. The coordinate conversions to get from object space to camera space are handled in the `isLookingAtObject()` method.

Comment: @spakplug: Thank for the detailed explanation. Frankly speaking, I am not able to comprehend the `PITCH`, `YAW` even though you explained it in a simple manner. I will go through it again. Right now , I do have the original `circle` and `rectangle` coordinate and their respective `projection matrices`. I am computing the final coordinate by multiplying with their projection matrices and trying to check whether the `circle` point lies inside the `rect` transformed coordinate.

Comment: I will draw a diagram and update my answer tonight to make it clear.

Comment: Thanks a million for the detailed explanation. I am going through it and will go until and unless I get a grasp of it and able to solve my problem. I will again try to use the `TreaseHuntActivity` sample as well. Thank you.

Comment: Good luck with it :)

Comment: One thing I am curious about, how to calculate the `YAW` and `PITCH` limit. Is there any formula for it based on rectangle width and height.

Comment: It is simple right angle triangle trigonometry. The formula is similar for both cases. For instance, to derive the formula for phi, look at cross section Y-e. Draw a line from P1 to e,and P2 to e. Now you have 2 right angle triangles, use tan of the vertical length / horizontal length to calculate phi for each triangle.  PITCH_LIMIT is the difference between the two angles.  Same calculation applies for theta.

Comment: Thanks, I will try that as well. So far I was able to select a big rectangle with the given formula and the explanation you have given. Inside my big rectangle there are various small rectangles with uniform width and height similar to gallery grids. I calculated the center position and applied the formula you have given. Selection works for center object only and for other objects, there is wrong selection. Maybe I am doing something wrong. I am working on it. Thanks

Comment: To be sure `POS_MATRIX_MULTIPLY_VEC` means the center position of the rectangle, `modelCube`  is 4x4 matrix defining the scale, rotation and translation for the centre point and `modelView` is an identity 4x4 matrix. And `headView` in my case is `controller.orientation.toRotationMatrix` result.

Comment: I tried with all my effort, but couldn't make the formula work in my case. I will try with simple `x,y,z` boundary comparison of rectangle with the controller location and see whether it works or not.

Comment: Yes `POS_MATRIX_MULTIPLY_VEC` is just a matrix which when multiplied with the `modelView` will extract the point (x,y,z) coordinate. It sounds like you may have not defined your model and view matrices correctly. I did manage to find one tutorial which explains the treasureHunt application in a lot of detail, please check it here to see if you are defining your matrices correctly: https://developers.google.com/vr/android/samples/treasure-hunt

Comment: Thank you for all your help. I have been trying to understand and find the solution for a week now. Maybe my approach is wrong in some way. So far I was playing around with this https://github.com/androidlife/openingGL/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/openingl/vr/controller/SimpleControllerActivity.java, to test the logic. The logic only works when the object centre is `{0,0,0}` and when it is translated or moved, it won't work. Maybe be I am missing something. I will look again. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for all the detail diagram. I finally figured out due to your diagram and logic. Though, I still don't have a clear picture, what I came to know from you that using the vertices of the quad or rectangle , we can easily calculate, the `yaw` range and `pitch` range of any rectangle. Then we simply compare those range with the `controllers.yawPitchRollRadians` and see whether, the controller is pointing to the object or not. I will update the answer as well and thank you a million for your help, diagram and logic without which I couldn't have solved it.

Comment: Excellent! So happy you solved it! Please do make ammendments to my answer. Add an **edit** section to the answer where you make the changes.

Comment: Seems like my edit is being rejected. Should I wait more or should I add as a separate answer.

Comment: Up to you, it is probably a good idea to write a seperate answer in that case.

Comment: Let us wait for other reviewer as well and if it gets rejected, I will post it as a separate answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, one needs to look upon the above detailed description provided by [sparkplug](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1897312/sparkplug), which contains all the concepts related to the question. And I owe [sparkplug](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1897312/sparkplug) for providing such a great concept related to this problem without whom, it would have been impossible to find the answer.

Moving on, if you have trouble understanding what `atan2` does, then please follow this  [link](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/14602/what-are-atan-and-atan2-used-for-in-games). From trigonometry formula `tan(angle) = perpendicular/base` and if you have `perpendicular` and `base` values `atan2` will give the angle. Basically `atan2` will give the angle between two points. In our case point 1 being origin `0,0,0` and other point being the center point of rectangle or any vertices of the rectangle. So the difference between origin and point in rectangle will simply be the point values i.e. `x-0 = x, y-0 = y, z-0 = z`. Further, in our case we are calculating angle with reference to `z axis` i.e our `base`.

If you are having some difficulty in understanding the concept of `YAW` and `PITCH`, I will make an analogy to head movement. Make your head straight and look in the forward direction, then move your head left and then move your head right. This is `YAW` i.e. the angle your head is moves in the left and right direction. Again make your head straight and look in the forward direction, then move your head up and down. This is `PITCH` i.e. by how much angle your head moves up and down.

Making an analogy to head movement, the point between your neck and head is the pivot point. Moving your head upwards and downwards, your eyes will be scanning in the `PITCH` direction. Likewise, taking the same pivot point, moving your head from left to right, your eyes will be scanning in the `YAW` direction.

In this solution, we need to calculate the angle in which our head is to be moved to scan the whole rectangle in width and in height.

Moving on, take the above analogy and study the [daydream controller sample](https://github.com/googlevr/gvr-android-sdk/blob/master/samples/sdk-controllerclient/src/main/java/com/google/vr/sdk/samples/controllerclient/ControllerClientActivity.java). You need to study the `YAW` and `PITCH` value it gives. To make study simple, put the controller flat in the table with touchpad away from you. Then just move slightly the controller in left and right direction in the manner you spin a bottle in the table. You will notice the range of `YAW` values. Then gently pick up the controller and just move up and down. This will give the range of `PITCH` values of the controller. For simplicity, our controller will be set as the origin, or to make the problem even simpler, you can consider the controller as your head situated in the origin and we are observing the values the controller emits when doing `YAW`ing and `PITCH`ing.

Try to put everything in normalized coordinates before calculating the `YAW` and `PITCH` values. Let us consider a rectangle with following coordinates

```
Vertices:  X     Y     Z
      P1: 0.52   0.76  -2.40  //LeftTop
      P2: 0.52   0.21  -2.40  //LeftBottom
      P3: 1.54   0.21  -2.40  //RightBottom
      P4: 1.54   0.76  -2.40  //Right Top
Formula:  
    YAW: Math.atan2(x,-z)
  PITCH: Math.atan2(y,-z)
//Then yaw, pitch values for above vertices will be
         YAW   PITCH
     P1: 0.21  0.31  //LeftTop
     P2: 0.21  0.09  //LeftBottom
     P3: 0.57  0.09  //RightBottom
//We don't require P4 here
      YAW Left: 0.21 ( P2 or P1 YAW)
      YAW Right: 0.57 ( P3 YAW )
    PITCH Top: 0.31 ( P1 PITCH )
    PITCH Bottom: 0.09  ( P2 or P3 PITCH )
// let us find the pitch and yaw values of controllers as well
   angles = controller.orientation.toYawPitchRollRadians
   angles[0]: YAW
   angles[1]: PITCH
   angles[2]: ROLL
 //of controller
 // controller YAW moves positive to negative from left to right, but in 
 // normalized coordinates, negative to positive from left to right, so to 
 // match controller's YAW values
      YAW Left: 0.21 * -1 ( P2 or P1 YAW)
      YAW Right: 0.57 * -1 ( P3 YAW )
    PITCH Top: 0.31 ( P1 PITCH )
    PITCH Bottom: 0.09  ( P2 or P3 PITCH )
 // and to know whether the controller is at the rectangle or not we simply do
    public boolean isOnRectangle(float[] angles) {
    return angles[0] <= yawLeft && angles[0] >= yawRight
            && angles[1] <= pitchTop && angles[1] >= pitchBottom;
}
```

The above will return true if the controller pointer falls in the rectangle and false otherwise.